# How to prevent Timer slowing down in background

Tags: swift, macos

I am writing a Mac OS app in Swift and want to repeat a task every 0.5s (more or less, high precision is not required). This app should run in the background while I use other applications.

I'm currently using a `Timer`:

`Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true)`

It starts fine with updates roughly every 0.5s but after some time in the background, the Timer slows down considerably to intervals of roughly 1s or 2s (it's very close to these values to it seems that the timer skips ticks or has a slowdown of a factor 2 or 4).

I suspect it's because the app is given a low priority after a few seconds in the background. Is there a way to avoid this? It can be either in the app settings in XCode by asking to stay active all the time, or possibly from the system when the app is run (or even but doing things differently without `Timer` but I'd rather keep it simple if possible).

Here is a minimal working example: the app only has a ViewController with this code

```
import Cocoa


class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var lastUpdate = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) {
            timer in
            let now = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
            print(now - self.lastUpdate)
            self.lastUpdate = now
        }
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
    }
}
```

Output at start is

```
0.5277011394500732
0.5008649826049805
0.5000109672546387
0.49898695945739746
0.5005381107330322
0.5005340576171875
0.5000457763671875
...
```

But after a few seconds in the background it becomes

```
0.49993896484375
0.49997520446777344
0.5000619888305664
1.5194149017333984
1.0009620189666748
0.9984869956970215
2.0002501010894775
2.001321792602539
1.9989290237426758
...
```

If I bring the app back to the foreground, the timer goes back to 0.5s increments.

Note: I'm running Mac OSX 10.15.5 (Catalina) on an iMac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the [App Nap](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/AppNap.html). You can disable App Nap but it is not recommended.

```
var activity: NSObjectProtocol?
activity = ProcessInfo().beginActivity(options: .userInitiatedAllowingIdleSystemSleep, reason: "Timer delay")
```

The default [tolerance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415085-tolerance) value of timer is zero but The system reserves the right to apply a small amount of tolerance to certain timers regardless of the value of tolerance property.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. AppNap is probably the cause of the problem as you suggest.
However, adding the `beginActivity` line didn't fix the problem (even with `.latencyCritical`). The timer still slows to 1 or 2 second increments after about 30 seconds.
I'd rather not disable AppNap system-wide but I can disable it for this specific app (it's an app I run manually while I use another program and needs to interact with the other program at regular intervals, but I quit it when I'm not running the other one)

Comment: Actually, disregard the previous comment. It seems to be working properly if I add the code you provided in `AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching` instead of `ViewController.init` as I was doing before.

Thanks a lot this seems to have solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment below, if you want granularities lower than 1.0 s, you should not use `Timer` objects, but rather `GCD`. I wrote a class `MilliTimer` you can use where you have improved granularity down to a few milliseconds. Please try this in a Playground and then in your app. In this example, I set the granularity of the timer based on GCD to 50 milliseconds. To adjust the delay pass the delay you want in milliseconds in the respective parameter of the initializer. In your case, you might be interested in 500 ms = 0.5 s.

```
import Cocoa

public class MilliTimer
{
    static let µseconds = 1000000.0
    static var lastUpdate = DispatchTime.now()

    var delay = 0
    var doStop = false
    var runs = 0
    let maxRuns = 50

    private class func timer(_ milliseconds:Int, closure:@escaping ()->())
    {
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(milliseconds)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
    }

    init(delay:Int) {
        self.delay = delay
    }

    func delta() -> Double {
        let now = DispatchTime.now()
        let nowInMilliseconds = Double(now.uptimeNanoseconds) / MilliTimer.µseconds
        let lastUpdateInMilliseconds = Double(MilliTimer.lastUpdate.uptimeNanoseconds) / MilliTimer.µseconds
        let delta = nowInMilliseconds - lastUpdateInMilliseconds
        MilliTimer.lastUpdate = now
        return delta
    }

    func scheduleTimer()
    {
        MilliTimer.timer(delay) {
            print(self.delta())
            if self.doStop == false {
                self.scheduleTimer()
                self.runs += 1

                if self.runs > self.maxRuns {
                    self.stop()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        doStop = true
    }
}

MilliTimer(delay: 50).scheduleTimer()
CFRunLoopRun()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this doesn't work on my computer. It still slows down after about 40 seconds, and actually gets stuck much longer.
The difference is that when it eventually fires, it fires all the misses events at the same time :
0.5000150203704834
0.5000100135803223
0.49916696548461914
10.499917984008789
5.507469177246094e-05
2.9802322387695312e-05
1.71661376953125e-05
1.3828277587890625e-05
2.9087066650390625e-05

Comment: I checked that in a playground and apparently the granularity of this setFireDate is 1.0 seconds, lower than that it apparently misfires. I always use a granularity of 60 s and I have no slow down whatsoever.